Ghosted by literary magazine?
I recently got published for the first time in a literary magazine for my poem. They're not very big, but have a considerate readership which is alright as a first for me.
Anyway, this said magazine was quite responsive in the beginning. They'd respond to my concerns within two or three days. The issue my poem is in was published more than a month ago.
They happen to be a paying magazine, but I haven't been paid yet. I asked them about the same ~three weeks ago but got no response. Mailed them once again 5 days ago and still haven't received any reply. I know people work part-time in most of such magazines, but here's the thing - they've been quite active on social media. So it is possible at least one of the editors is checking their email, although I'm not sure why they would purposefully ignore me.
Anyway, what should I do in such a situation? Should I keep spamming them after an interval or just sit and wait?

Have you ever read Marin Eden? Maybe it's time for good ol' fisticuffs. On more serious note, I hope it's just a misunderstanding and all will clear OK. I, however, recommend getting a telephone number or visiting the magazines office, if possible. for more direct (but still respectful) approach than emails.

@maelstromer Thanks for the comment, the issue has been resolved. Apparently they weren't checking their emails for some reason but they've apologized profusely and paid me. I was fairly certain that they'd scammed for a long while, so I can finally breathe now, haha.

What does your contract say about when you will get paid? After that period is over, wait for the legially specified grace period, if there is one, then send a payment reminder by registered mail and set a deadline. If they don't react after that, involve a laywer.
Research how this is done in your jurisdiction. There may be certain formalities that you have to follow (e.g. the deadline may have to be a minimum number of days).
You may want to ask about this on https://law.stackexchange.com. Do not forget to mention your jurisdiction.

There's no specific time period mentioned in the contract. They informally (?) told me that they'd be paying me before the launch, but due to problems from my side they could not. I resolved them within a week but I haven't received a response after that. Not sure why you've been downvoted.

I'd guess that given the likely amount you will wind up going via the small claims court rather than involving a lawyer. Details depend on where you are, but you can probably find out more by googling "small claims ".  But step 1 is always to write a formal letter ending with a demand for the money and "if I don't receive it within 1 month I will be forced to take legal action". I had a similar experience many years ago, and the letter did the trick.

@PaulJohnson As a published poet who’s been paid for some of his poems, it’s rare that a journal pays three figures for a poem. I’m guessing in this case it’s disorganization and the fact that Mel had issues on his side at payment time.

As someone who’s published poems (and been paid for some of those), legal action, even small claims court is unlikely to be worthwhile given the amounts involved (few venues pay more than two figures for a single poem, and those that do break the $100 mark don’t by much unless they’re a significant venue like Poetry or The New Yorker where this is unlikely to be an issue.
Since you mentioned in a comment that you had some problems on your side at payment time that prevented payment at that time, but I would guess that it’s largely an issue of organization than anything else. Polite persistence is your best path forward. Perhaps a PM¹ on the social media forum where you’re seeing activity.


If they don’t have DMs open² then a public comment, just saying something along the lines of “Hey, the payment issue on my side has been resolved, any sense of when you’ll send the payment for my poem?” would not be inappropriate, assuming you’re comfortable.

One reason I still have a Twitter³ account is for just this sort of thing.

I refuse to use the newer dumber name.


